# String.each iterating over chars?

Tags: groovy

I have a language question that's bothering me:

I've read an article about encoding from a fairly seasoned groovy developer (https://kousenit.org/2008/03/20/using-groovy-to-determine-unicode-characters)

In this snippet from the article:

```
def delimiters = [:]
def data = new File('pitcherrules.txt').text

data.each { c ->
    def str = Integer.toHexString(c as int)
    if (!(c =~ /\w/)) {
        delimiters[c] = str
    }
}
println delimiters
```

Shouldn't `c` inside the closure block be a `String` instead of a `char`?

For me the code breaks, for `c` is a String and then `c as int` throws an exception:

```
Caught: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "A"
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "A"
    at test$_run_closure1.doCall(test.groovy:5)
    at test.run(test.groovy:4)
```

I couldn't find any historical reasons either (say groovy 1.7 did treat it as `char` but doesn't anymore).

Anyone knows?

Comment: What exception you see? `c` inside the closure is of type `String`. The implementation of `each` method didn't change - it uses an `Iterator` from the object you call each method on. In case of a string, it returns an iterator that produces 1 character long strings. I just tried Groovy 1.7.11 and 2.5.8, both does the same. E.g. calling `"test".each { c -> println c.dump() }` dumps for strings.

Comment: That should be collect and findAll

Comment: @SzymonStepniak the code works for you if you have letters in the text? Because since `c` is of type `String`, `c as int` breaks. i.e `'a' as int`.
Will complement the question with the exception.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak replacing it with `(c as char) as int` works. But my question is did it work like the article before? Because I suppose the article is correct, since the author is a fairly experience Groovy developer/author/contributor.

Comment: @ijverig, even in groovy 1.5 the method `toList(String)` returns List of Strings. This method called before `String.each{...}`. https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_1_5_X/groovy/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L10312

Comment: Um, I believe the key is in `new File('pitcherrules.txt').text` as getText returns a String. As such, `data` is a String and doing each on a String iterates over the Strings characters. As such, `c` becomes a char.